# Strange characters when saving emoji in the database. Is this normal?

Tags: mysql, utf-8, utf8mb4

Emoji's are saved in my database (phpmyadmin) like `ðŸ˜‹ðŸ˜‰ðŸ˜ŽðŸ˜€ðŸ˜ƒ` (input via form). It seems weird characters to me or is this normal? They are displayed on my website in the right way. So, there's not a real problem, but I want to make sure these weird characters are right. My table and text fields have character sets utf8mb4_general_ci and and I use `<meta charset=utf-8>` on the html-page.

## Update

I went further research, but I have not yet come to a solution. The mojibake have become question marks. These emoji’s now makes me cry… hopefully someone knows what I am doing wrong.

I have tried to convert everything to utf8mb4 and utf8mb4_unicode_ci (server,database, table and column).

I even set in my.cnf:

```
[client]

default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysql]

default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysqld]

character-set-client-handshake = FALSE

character-set-server = utf8mb4

collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

If I look at the global variables, the output looks good:
[image]

If, however, I look at the variables, the following will happen:
[image]

I also looked at the Q & A:

**Question Marks (Señor for Señor):**

1. The bytes to be stored are not encoded as utf8 / utf8mb4. Fix this. *How can i fix this?*
2. The column in the database is not CHARACTER SET utf8 (or utf8mb4). Fix this. (Use SHOW CREATE TABLE.). *The column has the right character set (utf8mb4).*
3. Also, check that the connection is UTF-8. *How can i check this?*

My test-form is like this:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$con = mysqli_connect('*','*','*','*') or exit();

mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8mb4"); /// without this, it become latin1

///mysqli_query($con, "SET character_set_results = 'utf8mb4', character_set_client = 'utf8mb4', character_set_connection = 'utf8mb4', character_set_database = 'utf8mb4', character_set_server = 'utf8mb4'");


include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/assets/errors_and_warnings.php');

echo mysqli_character_set_name($con);

echo $_POST['action'];

if (!empty($_POST['bericht'])) {
    
    $bericht = $_POST['bericht'];
    
} else {
    
    $bericht = 'leeg';
}

echo $bericht;

if (isset($_POST['action'])) {

mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO test (bericht, datum)
                         VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $bericht)."',
                                 NOW())")
            or exit (mysqli_error($con));
}

?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Formulier</title>
</head>

<body>
    
<br><br>
    
    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="<?php $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>" method="post" name="test" id="test">

      <input name="action" type="hidden" id="action" value="topicplaatsen" />
        
        Bericht:<br />
        
        <textarea name="bericht" cols="40" rows="10" id="bericht">Proeftekst</textarea><br><br>
    
    <input name="imageField" type="image" src="../vormgeving/2010/button/verstuur_blauw.gif"/>
    
    </form>
    
</body>
    
</html>
```

I am using mysql version 5.5.60.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Answer (score 1):

`ðŸ˜‹ðŸ˜‰ðŸ˜ŽðŸ˜€ðŸ˜ƒ` is Mojibake for .

It usually means that `latin1` was involved somewhere in the processing.  For Emoji, you need `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`, *not* just the old `utf8`.

[*This Q&A*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) should help you figure out what step is missing.

One (of several) things it says:  HTML forms should start like `<form accept-charset="UTF-8">`

**More**

The `GLOBAL VARIABLES` look correct; the `SESSION VARIABLES` seem not to have picked up the global values *or* something is overriding them.

- Did you fail to reconnect?
- You could add `$con->set_charset('utf8mb4');` after connecting and before doing the various other queries.
- Check for errors after each use of `$con`.

Comment: Thnks! I tried some things. I have updated my question.

Comment: Well, I added some stuff, too.